# objdump: can't disassemble for architecture UNKNOWN!

Tags: disassembly

I am trying to use `objdump -d fileName` on a s-rec file and it returns unknown architecture, however it recognizes `fileName: file format srec`

I looked at `objdump --help` and under supported targets srec and symbolsrec is listed.

I have tried

`objdump -d -M srec myFile`

`objdump -d -m srec myFile`

What is the best way to tackle this? Alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SREC (aka S-Record) format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SREC_(file_format)) is similar to raw binary - it contains just the byte values but, unlike ELF, no metadata about the CPU or OS used.

If you know the CPU used, you can pass it to `objdump` with the `-m` switch, e.g.:

`objdump -m arm -D file.srec`

Normally `objdump` should recognize the format automatically but you can also specify it explicitly with `-b srec`

Common CPUs used with these files include former Motorola series such as 6800/6812 (and derived Freescale's HC12), 68K/Coldfire but sometimes also others, e.g. 8051

Use `objdump -i` to list the processors and file formats supported by your build . You may need to make a custom binutils build to support your target CPU.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, as a matter of fact my target is the Motorola series. Using `objdump -i` I don't see it listed, so I might have to go the custom build path...

Comment: You're were using a .srec file not the binary file itself. Either use the binary or use suggested `-b srec` argument: _Specify that the object-code format for the object files is bfdname. This option may not be necessary; objdump can automatically recognize many formats._


In other words, you specify the format of the binary not the targeted architecture.
S-Record or srec format: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Record

Answer (score 0):

In case this ends up being useful for anyone else, I had the same exact error, but it was in a cross-compilation project. My problem was that my CMake toolchain was erroneously setting CMAKE_OBJDUMP to /usr/bin/objdump instead of /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump. I fixed this by forcing my toolchain.cmake file to use /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump and /usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-objcopy, by adding these lines to my toolchain.cmake BEFORE any calls to find_program(...):

```
unset(CMAKE_OBJCOPY CACHE)
unset(CMAKE_OBJDUMP CACHE)
```

My CMake version is 3.16.3. I submitted a bug report for this here: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20787